# Upload file with python requests not working

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

**Note:** I've already read all related questions & answers and tried that solutions without success.

I'm trying to upload file to the server with the following code:

```
with open('test.mp4', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post(
        url,
        headers={
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        data=f
    )
```

But request always fails with:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))`

I've also tried to send it as `files`, not `data`.

I'm sure that server works fine, because if I send the same file to the same URL with curl it works:

```
curl -vvv -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "data=@test.mp4"  "https://vu.mycdn.me/upload.do?someskippedparams"
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this should work

```
with open('test.mp4', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post(
        url,
        headers={
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        files={ "data": f},
    )
```

But somehow it fails for your server.
Providing file name and mime type explicitly seems to solve the problem.

```
fname = "test.mp4"

with open(fname, "rb") as f:
    r = requests.post(
        url,
        files=[
            ("data", (os.path.basename(fname), f, "video/mp4")),
            ]
    )

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: thanks @int_32, I was posting too quickly. And here one sees again. one should never answer without testing / double checking.
Fixed my answer

Comment: thanks, I've tried this variant, it does not work too (same error)

Comment: perhaps the file is too big for the server. please try the second part of my modified answer. 

though the fact that you manage via curl indicates otherwise.

Do you really use the exact same url with exactly the same params?

Comment: I also renamed the file field to data, perhaps that was the reason. Pls retry

Comment: This variant does not work too. Files is fine, it's just 2 mb and can be successfully sent with curl (as I posted in the question).

Comment: So now you use the `files` param to upload the file and the file dict has the key `"data"` and your url is 100% identical?

And it still fails?

Try to remove the `data` param. WIll cahnge answer

Comment: I passed the mime type explicitly. Perhaps this was the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}

params = (
    ('someskippedparams', ''),
)

files = {
    'data': ('test.mp4', open('test.mp4', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('https://vu.mycdn.me/upload.do', headers=headers, params=params, files=files)
```